# Automatically changing block variables and collecting data from a model

Tags: matlab, loops, automation, simulink

I have a relatively basic Simulink block Model in which there is a Gaussian Noise Generator & an Error rate calculator. I want to get data on how changing the "variance" property of the Gaussian noise generator affects the result from the error rate calculator.

The most obvious way to do this is to manually run the simulation, record the results, change the variance of the Gaussian Noise Generator, rerun etc.

However, is there a way of getting the Simulink model to run the model, increase the Gaussian Noise variance by an amount, and rerun automatically for x number of iterations, and then to store the results in a list or array?

I am damn sure there is, but being new to Matlab & Simulink I have no idea of how to go about doing it? Somehow I imagine it would involve setting the "variance" as an input, and collecting the figure from the error rate calculator as an output - but again, I don't really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a `for` loop, and within the loop use the functions `set_param` and `sim`.

Look at the doc for more on how to use those functions.

There are also a couple of examples of using `set_param` [here](http://goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-creating-using-matlab-code.html) and using `sim` [here](http://goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-interfacing-with-matlab.html#CommandLineSim).

Comment: Thanks! After pouring over these pages I finally got it working! It takes several minutes to run the simulation 100 times but that's not too bad in the long run!

Comment: you can avoid set_param by using a variable name in the dialog box, and defining that variable to the desired value in the matlab workspace.

Comment: @JoeSerrano thats what I did - I don't know much about Matlab and the scope of variables but I wasnt sure how to add a param to the block that was within the scope of set_param so I simply did it this way instead (and to my shock, it worked!)

Comment: Yes, in this case, defining a MATLAB variable is far simpler than using set_param.